# SVG: dynamically crop a specific PATH element

Tags: javascript, svg, path, crop

I'm going mad cause I'm not able to achieve my target.

I need to dynamically crop the level of the tank (silo) that is pointed by the dasched line rectangle in the image attached.
According to the real percentage level I want to use Javascript to crop the portion of the image managed by a specific PATH of the G element.

I'm able to point via JS to that element without any issue, but how to crop it?

I used this portion of code:

```
path.style.fill = "#feca00";
path.style.height = 10;
path.setAttribute("height", perc_value);
```

all rows are working because I can see that the value are changed in DOM element accordingly but only the color fill style takes effect, nothing happened to the other two.

Please can someone help me, lighting my steps?

thank you

[image: Basic Silo (tank) Image]

Comment: Add a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click.

Comment: path elements don't support height as an attribute. You likely just need to apply a clipPath to the path to clip it to what you want.